# royale-ros: errors when linking with royale SDK libraries

Tags: catkin-make, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build the ROS package [royale-ros](https://github.com/lovepark/royale-ros).

I installed the most recent royale SDK as described [here](https://github.com/lovepark/royale-ros/blob/master/doc/royale_install.md) as a debian package.

When I try to build the package with `catkin_make` as described [here](https://github.com/lovepark/royale-ros/blob/master/doc/building.md), I get the following errors while linking:

```
dominik@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws/royale$ catkin_make 
Base path: /home/dominik/catkin_ws/royale
Source space: /home/dominik/catkin_ws/royale/src
Build space: /home/dominik/catkin_ws/royale/build
Devel space: /home/dominik/catkin_ws/royale/devel
Install space: /home/dominik/catkin_ws/royale/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/dominik/catkin_ws/royale/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j1 -l1" in "/home/dominik/catkin_ws/royale/build"
####
[  0%] Built target _royale_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_Config
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target _royale_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_Stop
[  0%] Built target _royale_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_SetExposureTime
[  0%] Built target _royale_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_Dump
[  0%] Built target _royale_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_Start
[  0%] Built target _royale_ros_generate_messages_check_deps_ExposureTimes
[  4%] Generating C++ code from royale_ros/ExposureTimes.msg
[  8%] Generating C++ code from royale_ros/SetExposureTime.msg
[ 12%] Generating C++ code from royale_ros/Start.srv
[ 16%] Generating C++ code from royale_ros/Config.srv
[ 20%] Generating C++ code from royale_ros/Dump.srv
[ 25%] Generating C++ code from royale_ros/Stop.srv
[ 25%] Built target royale_ros_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target config
[ 29%] Building CXX object royale/CMakeFiles/config.dir/src/config.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable /home/dominik/catkin_ws/royale/devel/lib/royale_ros/config
[ 29%] Built target config
Scanning dependencies of target dump
[ 33%] Building CXX object royale/CMakeFiles/dump.dir/src/dump.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable /home/dominik/catkin_ws/royale/devel/lib/royale_ros/dump
[ 33%] Built target dump
Linking CXX executable /home/dominik/catkin_ws/royale/devel/lib/royale_ros/lscam
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `VTT for std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `std::logic_error::logic_error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `std::logic_error::logic_error(std::logic_error const&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::reserve(unsigned long)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `std::length_error::length_error(char const*)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `std::out_of_range::out_of_range(char const*)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::resize(unsigned long, char)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libspectre3.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_erase(unsigned long, unsigned long)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `std::logic_error::logic_error(char const*)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `std::invalid_argument::invalid_argument(char const*)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)@GLIBCXX_3.4.20'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_append(char const*, unsigned long)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream()@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `std::runtime_error::runtime_error(char const*)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libspectre3.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_construct(unsigned long, char)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `std::logic_error::logic_error(std::logic_error const&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libspectre3.so: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length@CXXABI_1.3.8'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `std::runtime_error::runtime_error(std::runtime_error const&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::getline<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, char)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_sync(char*, unsigned long, unsigned long)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_stringstream(std::_Ios_Openmode)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator>><char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_ostringstream()@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::compare(char const*) const@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::str() const@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::swap(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>, void (*)())@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `VTT for std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_istringstream()@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `VTT for std::__cxx11::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_replace(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libspectre3.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::compare(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::find(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/opt/libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit/bin/libroyale.so: undefined reference to `std::runtime_error::runtime_error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/dominik/catkin_ws/royale/devel/lib/royale_ros/lscam] Error 1
make[1]: *** [royale/CMakeFiles/lscam.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j1 -l1" failed
```

How can I fix this error? Is it an error caused by royale or do I have the wrong version of GLIBCXX_3.4.21 installed?

`apt-show-versions libstdc++6` shows the following:
`libstdc++6:amd64/trusty 7.2.0-1ubuntu1~14.04 uptodate`

`strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX` contains `GLIBCXX_3.4.21`:

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
[...]
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on a virtual machine with freshly installed ROS Indigo.

GCC --version is `gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4`.

I have been researching the whole day and can't find a solution. I think I don't have enough knowledge about C++, make and ROS to find the solution myself. Any help would be very appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282909/royale-ros:-errors-when-linking-with-royale-sdk-libraries/) by [thedomdom](https://answers.ros.org/users/33723/thedomdom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-02-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-16**:
Is this a cross-post of [lovepark/royale-ros#2](https://github.com/lovepark/royale-ros/issues/2)?

**Comment by [thedomdom](https://answers.ros.org/users/33723/thedomdom/) on 2018-02-16**:
Yes, it is a cross-post. I'm a little bit frustrated tbh.
The problem is, that they can't really help me.
Furthermore, I get a similar (also GLIBCXX_3.4.21 related error), when I try to use this library: https://github.com/code-iai/pico_flexx_driver.
So you think that it is a `royale` error?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-17**:
Btw: this situation (with your cross-post on the `royale-ros` issue tracker and one here) is exactly why cross-posts are frowned upon: both me (and by extension the ROS Answers community) *and* the `royale-ros` devs are now suggestion possible solutions, without knowing this from one another.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-17**:
I was about to try and see whether I could quickly check what is going wrong with the `royale-ros` pkgs with the `3.11` SDK, but, apart from the fact that I don't appear to be able to access the SDK, I also just read that a `royale-ros` dev is going to do the exact same thing. I realise that ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-17**:
.. from your perspective having multiple people try and troubleshoot your issue looks like a good thing, but in reality it's essentially just duplicated (and wasted) effort for me and the `royale-ros` dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This could be an incompatibility between the libraries provided by the SDK (`libroyale-3.12.0.44-LINUX-x86-64Bit`) and the objects output by the compiler on your own system. I would think the developers of the package should be able to help you best.

---

Edit:

> Furthermore, I get a similar (also GLIBCXX_3.4.21 related error), when I try to use this library: https://github.com/code-iai/pico_flexx_driver.

That last pkg seems to depend on the same Royale SDK, so seeing the same errors doesn't surprise me.

You write you run Ubuntu 14.04, did you install any additional/upgraded compilers/libstdc++ pkgs?

Do you know whether the SDK is supposed to be compatible?

Can you check a clean Docker container?

---

Edit2:

> So I tried to use royale-ros and with the royale version 3.11 but unfortunately it did not work.
> The error was  `ld: cannot find -lroyale` [..]

That sounds like a linker (search) path error.

> even if I installed royale with `dpkg`.

that doesn't really make it special, so I'm not surprised.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thedomdom](https://answers.ros.org/users/33723/thedomdom/) on 2018-02-16**:
Yes, I upgraded libstdc++6. `apt-show-versions libstdc++6` showed the following (but did not work either):
`libstdc++6:amd64/trusty 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 upgradeable to 7.2.0-1ubuntu1~14.04`

Apart from that, I did not install or upgrade any compiler.

**Comment by [thedomdom](https://answers.ros.org/users/33723/thedomdom/) on 2018-02-16**:
Yes, the SDK should be compatible to Ubuntu 14.04. At least the pmd developers write in their  `README.md` that this Royale version has been tested on Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 16.04.

EDIT: You are right, the 3.12 version is not compatible to Ubuntu 14.04. I looked in the readme of version 3.11.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-16**:
Using the `3.11` version it does work? Could be a C++11 vs C++03 ABI problem.

**Comment by [thedomdom](https://answers.ros.org/users/33723/thedomdom/) on 2018-02-17**:
So I tried to use royale-ros and with the royale version 3.11 but unfortunately it did not work.
The error was  `ld: cannot find -lroyale` even if I installed royale with `dpkg`.
I also tried out pico_flexx_driver with 3.11 but there was another error.

**Comment by [thedomdom](https://answers.ros.org/users/33723/thedomdom/) on 2018-02-17**:
I am now just using the `sampleROS` driver from the 3.11 royale SDK and it works fine (I an see the point cloud in rviz).